# Increment and decrement EditTextInput

Tags: android, kotlin

is there a way to do this:

```
  var num = 0
    plusbtn.setOnClickListener {
        num++
        textView2.text = num.toString()
    }
    minbtn.setOnClickListener {
        num--
        textView2.text = num.toString()
    }
```

but instead of the textView2, I use a inputtype thing. So that I can still type the numbers in it, but also use the 2 buttons to increment en decrement.

Comment: Maybe use EditText with android:inputType="number" and have an onTextChangeListener on it, updating the num var.

Comment: you can use EditText and use method editText2.setText(num.toString())

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadRioPermana that worked. Only when I clicked the plusbtn, it goes to 4 and then when I type 6 in it, and then press the plusbtn. It goes to 5

Comment: Because you are storing the value one var that is not the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made this. This now works as I want it to:

```
 plusbtn.setOnClickListener {
        if(isEmpty(penaltytimetxt.text)){
            penaltytimetxt.setText("0")
        }
        num = penaltytimetxt.text.toString().toInt()
        if(num < 99){
            num++
            penaltytimetxt.setText(num.toString())
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Penalty time cannot go over 99 sec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
 minbtn.setOnClickListener {
        if(isEmpty(penaltytimetxt.text)){
            penaltytimetxt.setText("0")
        }
        num = penaltytimetxt.text.toString().toInt()
        if(num > 0){
            num--
            penaltytimetxt.setText(num.toString())
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Penalty time cannot go under 0 sec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in TextInputEditText yo should use setText method

```
var num = 0
plusbtn.setOnClickListener {
    num++
    textView2.setText(num.toString())
}
minbtn.setOnClickListener {
    num--
    textView2.setText(num.toString())
}
```